# Disable Column Wpf Data Grid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

i have a problem i have some data in my data table there are 12 column in this whenever i want to bind it to a wpf datagrid(i want that first to column is to hidden) and all other are shown in grid

how can i do this thanks

shashank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datgridname.Columns[7].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

its too simple

sorry for ask this